# accept input type="file" property doesn't work with custom type

Tags: html

Any solution  to upload custom mime types usign HTML5 ? the examples below don't work

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" accept=".pf12,.pfx">
<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" accept="*.pf12,*.pfx">
```

Comment: Before the file is uploaded, you can check the file's extension using Javascript, and prevent the form being submitted if it doesn't match.

Comment: yes i can do it with javascript , and i can do it also on the server side , but  I am wondering if there is a way to select the right type directly on the browser window

Comment: I think your extension files are too special. Maybe it was not supported :))